# Does moving a file/folder makes disk fragmented?

Tags: hard-drive, mv

Does moving a file/folder causes fragmentation in Disk on Ubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

moving a file with the `mv` command on the same disk does not move data. It changes only the directory entries relating to this data. Hence, it cannot fragment a disk.

Comment: Moving within same partition / filesystem does not move data physically. Moving between partitions / filesystems does !!

Comment: @SorenA Thank you. I am well aware of thatm, but will clarify. Moving between partitions is a smaller problem with regard to fragmentation in any case...Oh I just saw, I already had mentioned it  (...I write **on the same disk**)

Comment: You are wrong. Why are moving between partitions on same disks a smaller problem than movin between disk in relation to fragmentation ?

Comment: @SorenA You are right on this. I made a logical mistake on this. The answer is correct though, even if not complete.

Comment: Thanks everyone for information. I'm new to Linux and Ubuntu. I want to know whether drag-and-dropping a file/folder works in a similar way (does it only changes the directory entries) as using `mv` command does.

Comment: @ByteManager I am not sure about drag and drop (it is not in my workflow). Cut and paste on the same partition works like move (at least on KDE)

Answer (score 4):

In this article on Quora ['Does disk fragmentation occur in Linux? If not, why?'](https://www.quora.com/Does-disk-fragmentation-occur-in-Linux-If-not-why) it explains that Linux (EXT4) does not fragment any disk. Windows however will (FAT 32/NTFS).

Fragmentation only happens on HDDs (the ones with platters and readheads in them).So you can defrag them once in a while for better performance.

Fragmentation does not  happen on SSDs. Don't perform a defragmentation on these kind of disks. It is useless and the read/writes shorten its lifespan.

So it really depends on what kind of disk(s) you have in your system and what filesystem you use.

Comment: NVMes are a specific kind of controller interface for Solid State Drives (SSDs). The other kind of controller interface for SSDs and HDDs are called SATA. There is nothing called SDD.

Comment: @user68186 Thanks for editing my answer. And youŕe right about the controllers SATA and NVME.